# JMeter crawl in all web pages

Tags: http, jmeter

Is it possible to use JMeter to crawl (scrape) all pages referenced in a website? I am trying to use a HTTP request thread, but I don't see any options to do that.

Thanks

Comment: JUnit is a test framework so what are you trying to test here?

Comment: I want to benchmark the performance/memory on my website while calling random pages on my site.

Comment: You could setup Jmeter as a proxy and run a regular crawler on your site. Then convert the recorded retrievals into a loadtest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve there are at least 2 options:

1. The first thing which comes to everybody's mind is [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) -> [Spidering Example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#spider_example). Personally I don't like the approach as I believe that test needs to be **repeatable** and shouldn't go to external locations but you can give it a try, hopefully it'll work for you.
2. Use [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) in order to:

   - get all links from the page
   - get all links which belong to current domain only
   - exclude `callto:`, `mailto:`, etc. links

Example expression will look somehow like:

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'/') or starts-with(@href,'.') or contains(@href,'your.website.url') and not(contains(@href,'mailto'))]/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

`JUnit` can be used as a performance benchmark test framework but its not recommended as `JUnit` is mainly designed for Unit Testing. Here is a link to [JUnitPerf](http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html) that can be helpful:

> JUnitPerf is a collection of JUnit test decorators used to measure the performance and scalability of functionality contained within existing JUnit tests.

Some Helpful JUnit annotations to use would be:

- `@Repeat(times=30)`
- `@Test(timeout=221)`

`JUnitPerf` also has few APIs that you can readily use. You can use these APIs and use HTTP request threads to crawl the pages.

Comment: Oh very sorry! My question was about JMeter Sorry!